# no instance(s) of type variable(s) TContinuationResult exist so that TEntity conforms to Task<TContinuationResult

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-asynctask

I was trying to implement a repository system for the firestore database, However, I am getting the said error.
Further adding to error it says
Required type:Task 
Provided:Task

Here is my Repository class

```
public class FirestoreRepository<TEntity extends Identifiable<String>> implements Repository<TEntity, String> {


    private final Class<TEntity> entityClass;

    private final CollectionReference collectionReference;
    private final String collectionName;

    public FirestoreRepository(Class<TEntity> entityClass, String collectionName) {
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
        this.entityClass = entityClass;

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        this.collectionReference = db.collection(this.collectionName);
    }

    //Some interface function implementations go here, which we're working fine

    @Override
    public Task<TEntity> whereEqualToQuestionNumber(String id) {
        Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("questionNumber", id);

        Log.e(TAG, "Getting '" + id + "' in '" + collectionName + "'.");

        return query.get().continueWithTask(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    return documentSnapshot.toObject(entityClass);
                }
            }

               return entityClass.newInstance();
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my Repository Interface

```
public interface Repository<TEntity extends Identifiable<TKey>, TKey> {
    Task<Boolean> exists(TKey id);

    Task<TEntity> get(TKey id);

    Task<Void> create(TEntity entity);

    Task<Void> update(TEntity entity);

    Task<Void> delete(TKey id);
}
```

If you want to take look at full code, I have drawn inspiration from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/NiPfi/f00dc0f8178ef907202ed1046ced2746)